# Rails routing help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I want the url of a user post to be like this:

> example.com/users/username/post-name

How should I set this up?

Currently, the post model contains:

```
def to_param
    name.parameterize
end
```

(to hyphenate the post name accordingly)

routes.rb contains:

```
  map.resources :users
  map.resources :posts
```

Preferably, I would like to say post_path(post) and this would generate the appropriate path for me by finding the post.user automatically.

What do I need to do to make this happen?

**Also added**

```
map.resources :users do |user|
    user.resources :posts
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way more:

```
map.resources :users do |user|
  user.connect ':name/:action', :controller => 'posts', :defaults => {:action => 'show'}
end
```

Available routes:
example.com/users/username/post-name
example.com/users/username/post-name/edit (any action)

Comment: in this case if you acces route like /users/first/second then params[:name] = second and params[:user_id] = first

Answer (score 1):

Hi To make your application recognize routes like

```
example.com/users/username/post-name
```

you should add to your routes.rb

```
 map.connect 'users/:username/:post', :controller => "users", :action => "test"
```

Then you can access `params[:username]` and `params[:post]` inside your controllers `test` action  You should define it after `map.resources :users` but before `map ':controller/:action/:id'` but you must write your own helper then

Answer (score 0):

That to_param looks okay, but the builtin helpers don't link to nested resources like you want, you'd have to use `user_post_path(user, post)`. Ofcourse, you could write your own `post_path` helper method which does work the way you want.

```
def post_path(post)
  url_for [post.user, post]
end
```

Comment: This almost works.  It gives me a url like /users/username/posts/post-name. I don't want the 'posts' part of the url to exist.